# The star for favourites gives the same tool tip text regardless of state

Tags: discussion, user-interface, bookmarks

[image]
Regardless the state of a favourite star, the tool tip text is:

```
"Click again to undo".
```

When deselected, the tool tip text should read

```
"Click to mark as a favourite".
```

This follows [Steve Krug](http://sensible.com)'s "Don't Make me think" principle.

Comment: +1 Nice find! I hadn't noticed that myself either.

Comment: The same apply to the accepted answer check-box.  *Click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle*.

Comment: I just KNEW that star was the spawn of evil.

Comment: @squillman: upvote for mentioning the "spawn of evil" :P

Comment: The tooltip on the unseleted star reads "This is a favorite question (click again to undo)". I guess the "Click again to undo" part is fine but saying *"This is a favorite question"* looks **wrong**.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about this, I guess the part where it tells you `(click again to undo)` is fair, as it's just a *for your information* part. But the part where it says, `This is a favorite question`, that should be a typo, since it is not a favorite question.

Nice catch by you, but team should place a try block and remove this! And update it to something like this

> Click to mark it as a favorite question (Click again to undo)

Where the part inside the bracket would be taken as a *for your information* part.

That would be more like it when its not a favorite question and you need to favorite it.

Answer (score -8):

I think the message is clear enough.

It says:
"This is a favorite question (click again to undo)"

I don't think this needs to be explained any further, I understand it.

Comment: But if I haven't marked it as a favorite, it is *not* a favorite, therefore the tool tip is a dirty liar.  Also, if I haven't done anything, there is nothing to undo.  This tool tip is completely out of control!