# Small bug in favoriting questions

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The star for favourites gives the same tool tip text regardless of state.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39105/the-star-for-favourites-gives-the-same-tool-tip-text-regardless-of-state)

Believe me, it's small...

The tooltip of a Favorite-Button on a question which isn't favorited reads

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

Obviously, clicking again doesn't undo, rather, it *does*. Make sense?

Jack

Comment: The "click again to undo" bit is present in the tooltips for the voting arrows, too. But I thought it was pretty clear...?

Comment: I'm not really following what the bug is. You're saying if you click it once it doesn't undo? That's not clicking again, that's clicking

Answer (score 2):

I always interpreted that as a friendly "don't worry, you can always change this later" rather than as a bug.  Probably because of the "again"; saying "click again" assumes that you clicked a first time, to initially set it as a favorite.