# favourite question always on - a bug or a feature?

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, bookmarks, tooltips

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The star for favourites gives the same tool tip text regardless of state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39105/the-star-for-favourites-gives-the-same-tool-tip-text-regardless-of-state)
>   ["This is a favorite question" tooltip when not favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143350/this-is-a-favorite-question-tooltip-when-not-favorite)

This is just an observation while I use stackexchange website. Whenever I hover over the star on the question, I see the same caption

```
This is a favourite question (Click again to undo)
```

as if I had already marked it as a favourite question.

Even after starring it as my favourite question, I see the same caption when i hover on the star.

Is this a expected behaviour of the website or needs attention of the development team?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. It should probably say something like "star to mark as favourite" until you actually do so.

Comment: Or "click to mark as favorite."

Comment: Note that the tooltips for the voting arrows behave similarly, describing what the button's purpose is rather than its current state.

Comment: @Anna now that you have the power, why not change it yourself? :D